# Why aren't EM waves directionless?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I've seen some descriptions of electromagnetic waves of late, almost comparing the wiggling an electron (or any charge) to the disturbing of a water surface, and as a result waves are formed that propagate outwards.

My question is thus: why don't EM waves propagate in all directions (like a ripple), or are EM waves in fact doing that?

Comment: The "form" of an EM wave depends on the boundary conditions of the problem. The ripples spreading outwards is sort of like theEM waves produced by a small oscillating dipole (but they aren't on a 2d surface).

Comment: Water waves also aren't, in general, directionless, just look at the waves rolling towards shores, for instance, so why should EM waves be?

Comment: True, but they're localised, if you allowed them to water waves would diffract eventually, wouldn't they? And I'm really talking about if you moved your finger up and down in water, the waves would spread out radially.

Comment: @Jean-JacqduPlessis It's a bit surprising that waves with tiny wavelengths ($500\mathrm{nm}$ or so) behave almost exactly like rays over distances of meters. But they do. A water surface from throwing a rock into a pond will cause, what, maybe $30$ wavelengths to be visible at a moment? But with visible light, you're dealing with more like $10^7$ wavelengths in a comparable distance. At that scale, things are more like rays.

Answer (score 0):

Electromagnetic waves come in all shapes, sizes, and symmetries.

If you wiggle an electron back-and-forth, you will produce something-like [dipole-radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole#Dipole_radiation) which is fairly isotropic.  The same type of pattern will be produced if you wiggle your finger back-and-forth in water.  The strength of the resulting waves will be roughly isotropic, but somewhat smaller in magnitude perpendicular to the direction of your fingers motion.

When you look at these waves from far away, they can be approximated as [plane-waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_wave#Polarized_electromagnetic_plane_waves) - which might seem directional.

If you include obstacles (e.g. reflectors or absorbers) you can block some aspects of roughly isotropic em waves, to make them directional.  This is what happens in a laser or light-bulb, and analogous to what happens to water-waves moving through a channel, or through wave-breakers.

Finally, some types of em-wave sources are intrinsically more directional, like [synchrotron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrotron_radiation)/cyclotron radiation.  This is comparable to how wind or artificial wave machines produces water waves.